# how to call a certain function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am studying for a midterm in C and there is something unclear for me.

There is this code in the lectures but there is no extra detail on when and how to use it.

The code is:

```
void print_menu(char *options[], int dim);
```

How is that function supposed to be called, with what arguments?

I know how to call these function

```
void print_menu(char *options, int dim);
void print_menu(char options[], int dim);
```

Thank you

Comment: Without documentation, it is sometimes impossible to figure out how to call a function without looking at how the function is implemented. Unfortunately, this is often true of functions that are documented, because the documentation is insufficient.

Comment: There is no extra detail, just that one line in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char* options[]` is equivalent to `char** options` when it comes to parameters, so passing a pointer to a pointer to a `char` is alright:

```
char** ptr = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);

ptr[0] = "entry1";
ptr[1] = "entry2";
ptr[2] = "entry3";

print_menu(ptr, 3);

free(ptr);
```

OTOH, an array decays to a pointer when passed to a function, so passing a `char*[N]` is also OK, where `N` is the size of the array:

```
char* array[3] = { "entry1", "entry2", "entry3" };
print_menu(array, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

The prototype

```
void print_menu(char *options[], int dim);
```

is equivalent to

```
void print_menu(char **options, int dim);
```

You need to pass first argument of type  `char **` .